# Map PHP boolean to String t/f in Oracle

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine, mapping

I'm refactoring an old application with an Oracle database using Symfony2 and Doctrine. *I can't change the database scheme.*

I need a boolean value in the model, but the database saves it as VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) with t or f. How can I access *and* write t/f on Oracle side and use it as boolean in Symfony?

Thanks!

Mitja

Comment: why not overwrite getter and setter ? get() will return $this->property == 't'; while set will take a boolean and transform it into a 't' or 'f'

Answer (score 0):

Like this in your entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="somefield", type="string", length=1)
 */
private $someField;

/**
 * Set someField
 *
 * @param boolean $someField
 * @return ...
 */
public function setSomeField(bool $someField)
{
    $this->someField = 'f';

    if($someField)
        $this->someField = 't';

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get someField
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getSomeField()
{
    if($this->someField == 't')
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that as well Doctrine as Symfony FormBuilder both use reflection to access the property directly. The don't use the getters/setters.

Comment: I understand. Did you try to use a datatransformer in combination with the FormBuilder? (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)